# Incentives to Run a Full Node

Tags: node, economics

Is there any incentive to run a full node in IOTA? If not, what makes people to run full nodes and how they keep them running if there are no economical returns out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, other than supporting the community (or if you're a business implementing the Tangle internally) there is little incentive to run a full node. The expectation is that the introduction of Qubic (no ETA) will also bring incentives to run full nodes.